# Set Y under nav bar with autolayout

Tags: ios

i have a segmented control with auto layout.

```
    self.segment.frame = CGRectZero;
    [self.segment setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.segment setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.segment];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.segment
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.segment
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:0.28
                                                       constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.segment
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];
```

And when i build my project on Air or bigger screen then 5s, the segment is under navigation bar (about 30px) - with 5s or less is under nav bar without white space.

[image]

Is there any solution to set Y to under nav bar, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's your multiplier, which looks arbitrary - it looks like you tried to find a value that worked for the 5S - 0.28, and then hoped it would work elsewhere.  The problem is that you appear to be anchoring it to the parent window, so when the window is taller, the offset is greater.  You should instead have a constant offset depending on what margin you are anchoring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the navigation bar is 64px (44px + 20px for the status bar). The view controller's view will usually* extend under it. In that case, use

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.segment
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 multiplier:1
                                                   constant:64]];
```

to align the segmented control exactly to the top of the navigation bar.

*: extending is the default - you can override this in the storyboard or with the [edgesForExtendedLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout) property.